# Как передать параметр, по нажатию на флажок или checkbox формы в ajax используя jquery

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, forms, обработка

Доброго времени суток!
Вот форма
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу передавать по нажатию на параметр в форме средствами Jquery как ajax, на стороне сервера обработать цену параметра вернуть значение картинок новых, цен.
Можно это как то сделать через событие общее, ему передавать параметр, а оно уже вызывает Ajax??

Comment: Конечно всё это можно. Есть элементы формы, при их изменении вы считываете все нужные параметры, создаёте запрос, перерисовываете страницу. А вопрос-то у вас в чём? Может вы не слышали про `onchange`? Пропишите туда вызов своей функции, внутри делайте ajax. Форма просто немаленькая, поэтому желательно всё это красиво разделить на отдельные маленькие функции, но сам подход-то понятен?

Answer (score 0):

Слушайте у формы event change и отправляйте его на ваш скрипт.

```js
$(function() {
 $('form').on('change', function() {
   console.log($(this).serialize());
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Форсунок</legend>
    <label for="radio-1"><input type="radio" id="radio-1" value="forsunok-1" name="forsunok" checked>Форсунок 1</label>
    <label for="radio-2"><input type="radio" id="radio-2" value="forsunok-2" name="forsunok">Форсунок 2</label>
    <label for="radio-3"><input type="radio" id="radio-3" value="forsunok-3" name="forsunok">Форсунок 3</label>
    <label for="radio-4"><input type="radio" id="radio-4" value="forsunok-4" name="forsunok">Форсунок 4</label>
    <label for="radio-5"><input type="radio" id="radio-5" value="forsunok-5" name="forsunok">Форсунок 5</label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Меню</legend>
    <label for="menu-1"><input type="radio" id="menu-1" value="menu-1" name="menu">Меню 1</label>
    <label for="menu-2"><input type="radio" id="menu-2" value="menu-2" name="menu" checked>Меню 2</label>
    <label for="menu-3"><input type="radio" id="menu-3" value="menu-3" name="menu">Меню 3</label>
  </fieldset>
  <button type="reset">Сборс</button>
</form>
```